# undefined reference to _app_main

Tags: openmp, libgomp

I'm trying to run some tests on vsoc_beta using arm-elf-gcc and arm-rtems-gcc. However, both compilers gave me the same error:

```
/home/student/vsoc-beta/apps/libgomp/root.o: In function `main':
/home/student/vsoc-beta/apps/libgomp/libgomp.c:24: multiple definition of `main'
app_obj.o:/home/student/vsoc-beta/apps/rotate/rot.c:103: first defined here
/home/student/vsoc-beta/apps/libgomp/root.o: In function `main':
root.c:(.text+0x219c): undefined reference to `_app_main'
root.c:(.text+0x2298): undefined reference to `_app_main'
make: *** [o-optimize/app.exe] Error 1
```

These tests are using libgomp and in libgomp.c there's a line:

```
extern int _app_main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
```

and the main is defined as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
```

In the test files, there is another main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first error is a "Multiple definition of main" you must decide first which of the 2 main function you have is the application entry point.

An application as only one entry point or main function.